# R: Get column names where value is not null

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a table of 7 columns, the first column is id, then 3 columns of vegetable types and the last 3 columns are fruit types. The values indicate whether a person has this vegetable/ fruit. Is there a way to group the vegetables and the fruits, and output the column names if the person has that vegetable/ fruit?

Input data frame:

```
id1 <- c("id_1", 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA)
id2 <- c("id_2", NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA)
input <- data.frame(rbind(id1, id2))
colnames(input) = c("id", "lettuce", "tomato", "bellpeper", "pineapple", "apple", "banana")
```

Expected output data frame:

```
output_id1 <- c("id_1", "lettuce", "apple")
output_id2 <- c("id_2", "tomato, bellpeper", NA)
output <- data.frame(rbind(output_id1, output_id2))
colnames(output) <- c("id", "veg", "fruit")
```

Comment: If you're not interested in having "veg" and "fruit" in the return names, could you just remove these words altogether right from the start? Say, rename the input dataframe before doing any analysis.

Comment: Yes, that's doable. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the original `input` data you posted (also shown below in **Data**) you could do this with the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)

input %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = matches("^veg|^fruit"),
                      names_sep = "_",
                      names_to = c("type", "val"),
                      values_drop_na = T) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = id,
                     names_from = type,
                     values_from = val,
                     values_fn = function(x) paste0(x, collapse = ","))
```

**Output**

```
  id    veg              fruit
  <chr> <chr>            <chr>
1 id_1  lettuce          apple
2 id_2  tomato,bellpeper NA
```

---

**Data**

```
input <- structure(list(id = c("id_1", "id_2"), veg_lettuce = c("1", NA
), veg_tomato = c(NA, "1"), veg_bellpeper = c(NA, "1"), fruit_pineapple = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_), fruit_apple = c("1", NA), fruit_banana = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("id1", "id2"
))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick!

```
id1 <- c("id_1", 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA)
id2 <- c("id_2", NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA)
input <- data.frame(rbind(id1, id2))
colnames(input) = c("id", "lettuce", "tomato", "bellpeper", "pineapple", "apple", "banana")

# Remove the id column, it's not necessary
input_without_id <- dplyr::select(input, -c("id"))

# For each row (margin = 1) of the input, return the names vector (names(input))
# but only in the positions the where the row (x!) is not NA
result <- apply(input_without_id, MARGIN = 1, function(x) {
    return(names(input_without_id)[which(!is.na(x))])
})

# Rename the result with the corresponding ids originally found in input.
names(result) <- input$id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

input %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c('type', 'class'), sep = "_") %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  group_by(id, type) %>% 
  summarise(class = toString(class)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = class) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  select(id, veg, fruit)
```

This gives us:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  id    veg               fruit
  <chr> <chr>             <chr>
1 id_1  lettuce           apple
2 id_2  tomato, bellpeper NA
```